# How to open Files in flutter windows with default app

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I am able to open PDF file with the below code in flutter windows platform,

```
Process.run(
        'C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe', [_path]);
```

My problem is specifying the path to the app, it can be different!

Is there a way to open the file automatically with the Windows Standard App?

For example: .pdf files with Acrobath Reader, .txt files with Notepad, .csv with Excel ....etc

Thx for Help!

Answer (score 2):

The new answer is (I only care about Windows):

```
  // incoming path uses forward slashes
  Future<void> launchFile(String path, String file) async {
    if (file.isEmpty) {
      path = path.replaceAll("/", "\\"); // necessary for Windows
      await Process.start('explorer', [path]);
    } 
    else {
      ProcessResult result = await 
        Process.run('cmd', ['/c', 'start', '', '$path/$file']);
      if (result.exitCode == 0) {
        // good
      } 
      else {
        // bad
      }
   }
 }
```

The /c will close the cmd window after launch. Explorer seems to prefer backslashes.

I asked ChatGPT to tell me how to deal with spaces in filenames because I could not figure it out. Apparently I needed an empty parameter after 'start'.

Code is minimal to show the basics; add your own error detection/handling, etc.

Comment: thanks K J, but eventually I had to get ChatGPT to help me

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 API for this is ShellExecute
https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/ShellExecute.html

Example:

```
final verb = 'open'.toNativeUtf16();
final file = 'yourfile.pdf'.toNativeUtf16();
final params = ''.toNativeUtf16();
final path = 'C:\yourfolder\'.toNativeUtf16();
ShellExecute(0, verb, file, params, path, SW_SHOW);
```